# How to pin a cloth in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, objects, cloth-simulation

Take for example a flag, the cloth is pinned to a pole. I want to do the same thing in the blender game engine.

Comment: Is it possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloth is not supported in the BGE.

You can use the Physics Type Softbody.

You can pin the softbody with rigid body constraints.

Comment: May you please elaborate? we try to get full and complete answers that explain how to create the effect from square 1.